# How activity can listen to event from other class

Tags: java, android

It is possible listen to events from one class to other?

For example I have costume call:

```
public abstract class MyCall<T> implements Callback<T>  {

    //Active(); Listen to this

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

    //InActive(); Listen to this

    }
}
```

And I want to listen Active/Inactive inside my Activity, and make actions based on the state, for example:

```
  public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }
        @Override
        protected int getLayoutId() {
            return R.layout.activity_main;
        }

       @Override
       protected void onActive() {
        //do something
       }

       @Override
       protected void onInActive() {
        //do something
       }
         }
```

I hope I explain well my problem.

I believe the answer is somewhere around Interface but I can't think of a way of implemeting this, nor if it even possible to implement such a thing